# How can I copy STDOUT to a file without stopping it showing onscreen using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to copy stdout to a file for logging purposes. I also want it to display in the Ruby console of the IDE I'm using.

I inserted this code into my script and it redirects `$stdout` to the my.log file:

```
$stdout.reopen("my.log", "w")
```

Does anyone know of a gem or technique to copy the contents of `$stdout` to a file and not redirect it to a file? Also, I am not using Rails just Ruby.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this might help you:

```
class TeeIO < IO
  
  def initialize orig, file
    @orig = orig
    @file = file
  end
  
  def write string
    @file.write string
    @orig.write string
  end
  
end
```

Most of the methods in `IO` that do output ultimately use `write`, so you only have to override this one method. You can use it like this:

```
#setup
tee = TeeIO.new $stdout, File.new('out.txt', 'w')
$stdout = tee

# Now lots of example uses:
puts "Hello"
$stdout.puts "Extending IO allows us to expicitly use $stdout"
print "heres", :an, :example, "using", 'print', "\n"
48.upto(57) do |i|
  putc i
end
putc 10 #newline
printf "%s works as well - %d\n", "printf", 42
$stdout.write "Goodbye\n"
```

After this example, the following is written identically to *both* the console and to the file:

```
Hello
Extending IO allows us to expicitly use $stdout
heresanexampleusingprint
0123456789
printf works as well - 42
Goodbye
```

I won't claim this technique is fail proof, but it should work for simple uses of stdout. Test it for your use.

Note that you don't have to use `reopen` on `$stdout` unless you want to redirect output from a child process or an uncooperative extension. Simply assigning a different `IO` object to it will work for most uses.

---

#### RSpec

The RSpec command line takes a reference to `$stdout` *before* you can get any code to run to reassign it, so this doesn't work. `reopen` still works in this case as you're changing the actual object pointed to by both `$stdout` and the reference that RSpec has, but this doesn't give you output to both.

One solution is to monkey-patch `$stdout` like this:

```
$out_file = File.new('out.txt', 'w')

def $stdout.write string
  $out_file.write string
  super
end
```

This works, but as with all monkey patching, be careful. It would be safer to use your OS's `tee` command.

Comment: That's pretty cool but it's not exactly what I need. I want to print EVERYTHING that is printed to the screen when I run an rspec test. Specifically I am talking about the test results. These are generated by rspec and when I use $stdout.reopen I can redirect them to a file. I want them to print to both the screen and a file. I need a way to capture/clone $stdout and then write it to a file.

Comment: @Conner What happens if you use this instead of `$stdout.reopen`? What doesn't go into the file that gets printed to screen (or vise versa)?

Comment: All the "puts" statements go into the file but what doesn't go into the file are the rspec generated results. like...

Comment: .

Finished in 12.19 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Comment: @Conner Interesting. I've had a bit of a poke around at what rspec is doing. See my edit for a possible solution. It's a bit of a hack (although so was my original solution) but it might work for you.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for! It printed all the information I wanted to both the command line and a file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux or Mac OS, the `tee` command available in the OS makes it easy to do this. From its man page:

```
NAME
     tee -- pipe fitting

SYNOPSIS
     tee [-ai] [file ...]

DESCRIPTION
     The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.
```

So something like:

```
echo '>foo bar' | tee tmp.out
>foo bar
```

echos the output to STDOUT and to the file. Catting the file gives me:

```
cat tmp.out
>foo bar
```

Otherwise, if you want to do it inside your code, it's a simple task:

```
def tee_output(logfile)
  log_output = File.open(logfile, 'w+')
  ->(o) {
    log_output.puts o
    puts o
  }
end

tee = tee_output('tmp.out')
tee.call('foo bar')
```

Running it:

```
>ruby test.rb 
foo bar
```

And checking the output file:

```
>cat tmp.out
foo bar
```

I'd use `"w+"` for my file access to append to the output file, rather than over-write it.

*CAVEAT*: This opens the file and leaves it open during the life of the code after you've called the `tee_output` method. That bothers some people, but, personally, it doesn't bother me because Ruby will close the file when the script exits. In general we want to close files as soon as we're done with them, but in your code, it makes more sense to open it and leave it open, than to repeatedly open and close the output file, but your mileage might vary.

---

EDIT:

For Ruby 1.8.7, use `lambda` instead of the new `->` syntax:

```
def tee_output(logfile)
  log_output = File.open(logfile, 'w+')
  lambda { |o|
    log_output.puts o
    puts o
  }
end

tee = tee_output('tmp.out')
tee.call('foo bar')
```

Comment: I'm on a Windows 7 box. It's a work computer so I don't have the ability to switch to linux or Mac. I also cannot get this code to run for me. I'm getting an "syntax error, unexpected "{" expecting kEND".

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? If it's 1.8.7, see the edit.

Comment: Ok. The code works now but I'm still unsure how this helps me with my problem. It seems like this is just another way to write to a file. I'm a novice coder, could you please I can use this with $stdout?

Comment: It writes to a file AND to stdout. Effectively it does what `tee` would do. By default, `puts` uses `STDOUT` AKA `$stdout`. In other words, `puts` is `$stdout.puts` unless you change the device that `$stdout` points to.

Comment: Ok. I see what you're saying about writing to a file AND stdout. That's great but how do I use tee.call to write EVERYTHING stdout outputs to a file and not just 'foo bar'? Specifically I'm talking about things like Rspec results that are auto-generated. I would like to get every little bit of information that is outputted written to a file and the screen.

Comment: If the output you want is generated by an application writing to stdout, use the OS version of `tee`. If you are are generating that output from a Ruby script you wrote, then use the method-version. If you don't have `tee` available on your OS, then use the method-version and write a script that reads the output of the other program via a pipe ("`|`") and process it that way. This isn't a difficult task on Linux/Mac OS. I imagine there's a pretty simple answer on Windows too since it supports pipes and redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a old question, but I found myself in the same situation. I wrote a Multi-IO Class which extends `File` and overrode `write` `puts` and `close` methods, I also made sure its thread safe:

```
require 'singleton'

class MultiIO < File
  include Singleton 
  @@targets = []
  @@mutex = Mutex.new

  def self.instance
    self.open('/dev/null','w+')
  end

  def puts(str)
    write "#{str}\n"
  end

  def write(str)
    @@mutex.synchronize do 
      @@targets.each { |t| t.write str; flush }
    end
  end

  def setTargets(targets)
    raise 'setTargets is a one-off operation' unless @@targets.length < 1
    targets.each do |t|
       @@targets.push STDOUT.clone if t == STDOUT 
       @@targets.push STDERR.clone if t == STDERR
       break if t == STDOUT or t == STDERR  
       @@targets.push(File.open(t,'w+'))
    end
    self
  end

  def close
    @@targets.each {|t| f.close}
  end
end

STDOUT.reopen MultiIO.instance.setTargets(['/tmp/1.log',STDOUT,STDERR])
STDERR.reopen STDOUT 


threads = []

5.times.each do |i| 
  threads.push( 
    Thread.new do
      10000.times.each do |j|
        STDOUT.puts "out#{i}:#{j}"
      end
    end
  )
end

5.times.each do |i| 
  threads.push( 
    Thread.new do
      10000.times.each do |j|
        STDERR.puts "err#{i}:#{j}"
      end
    end
  )
end

threads.each {|t| t.join}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiny improvement from matts answer:

```
class TeeIO < IO
  def initialize(ios)
    @ios = ios
  end

  def write(string)
    @ios.each { |io| io.write string }
  end
end
```